# How can I fix this error? What you should pay attention to?

Tags: python-3.x, django

When starting the server, an error crashes, which file and piece of code should I pay attention to? Other answers given on this site did not help.

**Terminal:**

```
  File "/home/lab/ProjectsDjango/env_bookmarks/dj-bookmarks/bookmarks/account/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
  File "/home/lab/ProjectsDjango/env_bookmarks/bookmarks/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 22, in url
    return re_path(regex, view, kwargs, name)
  File "/home/lab/ProjectsDjango/env_bookmarks/bookmarks/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Next is my application code.

**Main urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin



urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
    ]
```

**App views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})

@login_required 
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

**App urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
    url(r'^logout-then-login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', name='logout_then_login'),
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    ]
```

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place and trying to find a bug where it isn't?

Comment: which version of django you are using?

Comment: @Tasnuva python = 3.8.2, django = (3, 1, 0, 'final', 0)

Comment: did you mean django 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using django>1.9: You cannot use strings as views. So you need to do something like this with all views:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    ......

]
```

Comment: **
ImportError: cannot import name 'login' from 'django.contrib.auth.views' (/home/lab/ProjectsDjango/env_bookmarks/bookmarks/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py)
**

I tried to do this, but I get this error @Tasnuva

Comment: use `from django.contrib.auth import login, logout` I have edited the answer.